# Caching strategy to reduce load on web application server

Tags: mongodb, caching, iis, coldfusion, memcached

What is a good tool for applying a layer of caching between a **webserver** and an **application server**.

**Basic Requirements:**

1. The application server needs a way to remove items from the cache and put items in the cache with an expiration date.
2. The webserver needs a way to pull items out of the cache in a very light-weight, fast manner without requiring thread allocation on the application server.
3. It does not neccessarily need to be a distributed cache (accessible from multiple machines), but it wouldn't hurt.

**Strategies I have considered:**

1. **Static file caching**. Request comes in, gets hashed, if a file exists we serve it, if not we route the request to the app server. Is high I/O a problem or file locking problems due to concurrency? Is it accurate that the file system is actually very fast due to kernel level caching in memory.
2. **Using a key-value DB like mongodb, or redis**. This would store the finished HTML/JSON fragments in db. The webserver would be equipped to read from the DB and route to the app server if needed. The app server would be equipped to insert/remove from the DB.
3. **A memory cache like memcached or Varnish** (don't know much about Varnish). My only concern with memcached is that I'm going to want to cache 3 - 10 gigabytes of data at any given time, which is more than I can safely allocate in memory. Does memcached have a method to spill to the filesystem?

Any thoughts on some techniques and pitfalls when trying this type of caching layer?

Comment: Mongodb/redis could easily cache some data, especially queries from SQL (this is roughly what twitter does with cassandra). Normally a good bet I have found is to mix semi perma cache such as MongoDB/redis with memcached, keeping small hot stuff in memcached for speed but making speed by storing aggregated bigger info in mongodb/redis

Comment: There is no significant difference between serving data from memcache and serving it from MongoDB/Redis provided the latter options have it in memory (MongoDB does when the data is hot enough, not 100% on Redis but I believe so). Another small issue with memcache is that it's distributed but not necessarily replicated. If a memcache node fails it'll have to restart cold which might cause issues for you.

Comment: If it's relevant, I'm not looking to cache "data". In most cases the cache will be full rendered HTML or HTML fragments. This isn't really meant as a way to reduce SQL queries. It's a way to reduce load on the entire application stack but moving a caching layer to the webserver.

Comment: You need to cache 10GB of HTML? That's...a lot, are you sure your not considering caching unneeded pages?

Comment: @sammaye I think of 10gb as the top end that we plan on never reaching but could. If we estimate 30k per page x 40 sites x 1250 pages = 10gb which is unlikely but possible. Either way it's beyond what is reasonable to store entirely in memory, right?

Comment: Maybe, hmm 40 sites...without knowing the scenario and that, like the intricate details I would say yes, you'd be better off with something like MongoDB in this case.

Comment: It looks like you will have pros and cons for every one of these methods, my personal preference would be 1). It would free extra resources on DB/Application servers to handle data preparation. To combat file locking I implemented request queueing between web server and application server. The complete setup looked like this: [front] (level 1) multiple load-balanced web-servers, (level 2) request caching/queueing mechanism, (level 3) application/DB server(s)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use GigaSpaces XAP in memory data grid for caching and even hosting your web application. You can choose just the caching option or combine the power of two and gain single management of your environment along other things.

Unlike the key value pair approach you suggested, using GigaSpaces XAP you'll be able to have complex queries such as SQL, object based temples and much more. In your caching scenario you should check out more specifically the local cache related features.

[Local Cache](http://wiki.gigaspaces.com/wiki/display/XAP91/Local+Cache)

[Web Container](http://wiki.gigaspaces.com/wiki/display/XAP91/Web+Processing+Unit+Container)

Disclaimer, I am a developer in GigaSpaces.

Eitan

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer this from the POV of using Coherence (http://coherence.oracle.com/):

*1. The application server needs a way to remove items from the cache and put items in the cache with an expiration date.*

```
// remove one item from cache
cache.remove(key);

// remove multiple items from cache
cache.keySet().removeAll(keylist);
```

*2. The webserver needs a way to pull items out of the cache in a very light-weight, fast manner without requiring thread allocation on the application server.*

```
// access one item from cache
Object value = cache.get(key);

// access multiple items from cache
Map mapKV = cache.getAll(keylist);
```

*3. It does not neccessarily need to be a distributed cache (accessible from multiple machines), but it wouldn't hurt.*

- Elastic. Just add nodes. Auto-discovery. Auto-load-balancing. No data loss. No interruption. Every time you add a node, you get more data capacity and more throughput.
- Automatic high availability (HA). Kill a process, no data loss. Kill a server, no data loss.

*A memory cache like memcached or Varnish (don't know much about Varnish). My only concern with memcached is that I'm going to want to cache 3 - 10 gigabytes of data at any given time, which is more than I can safely allocate in memory. Does memcached have a method to spill to the filesystem?*

- Use both RAM and flash. Transparently. Easily handle 10s or even 100s of gigabytes per Coherence node (e.g. up to a TB or more per physical server).

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views  expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the  opinions or views of my employer.*